# Numbers Divisible by 3 recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am writting a program that takes input using a series of numbers. Using recursion and Arrays I am trying to add all the numbers entered that are divisible by 3 and add them together. Ex. 3 4 5 6
Output should be 9. My current output keeps giving me 3 as the output for my entries. Any help or suggestions?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
public class Assignment9 {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{

    int i = 0;
    int [] nums;
    nums = new int [100];
    InputStreamReader inRead = new InputStreamReader(System.in);   
    BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(inRead);
    String line = buffRead.readLine();
    try {    
        while (line.equals("0") == false && i<100) {        
            i++;        
            line = buffRead.readLine();     
            nums[i]=(int) Double.parseDouble(line);     
        }      
    } catch(IOException e) {        
        System.out.println("Array index out of bound");   
    }   

    int endIndex = computeSumDivisibleBy3(nums, 0, nums.length-1);   

    System.out.print ("The minimum number is " + min + ('\n'));
    System.out.print ("The sum of the numbers divisible by 3 is " + endIndex + ('\n'));
}
}   


public static int computeSumDivisibleBy3(int [] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
if(startIndex == endIndex) {       
    if(numbers[endIndex] %3 == 0){                
        return (int) numbers[endIndex];            
    } else {                
        return 0;            
    }       
} else {           
    if(numbers[endIndex] %3 == 0) {               
        return (int) (computeSumDivisibleBy3(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1) + numbers    
    }
    else {       
        return computeSumDivisibleBy3(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);           
    }      
}
}
```

Comment: Could you format the code so it's a little easier to read?

Comment: If a number is divisible by `3`, `x % 3` will equal `0`, not `1`.

Comment: your method findMin doesnt exist ?

Comment: `if (startIndex % 3 == 1) {` seems like it should be `if (numbers[startIndex] % 3 == 0) {` - you want to check if the number in that position of the array is divisible by three, not if that position of the array is divisible by three.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I had 0 instead of 1 but it still did not work .

Comment: why are you using an array of doubles to check for divisibility by 3? int[] would be better, as no number except an integer will be perfectly divisible by 3.  If you are reading doubles in, then you can just dispose the ones that are not integers immediately.

Comment: Why did you remove all of the code?  Also if you have no resolved your issue, please post your updated code.  I'm sure it's something as simple as an index being missed, just not sure where without seeing what you did.

Answer (score 1):

Ok a few things here:

1) A number n is divisible by three if: `n%3 == 0` not `n%3 == 1`

2) When you check to see if a number is divisible by 3, you are checking if the INDEX is divisible by 3, not the actually number in the array (use numbers[endIndex])

Sort those two things out and it should work.  This seems like homework, so I'm wary to just give you the correct code rather than letting you work through it and understand it.

Once you get it working, I have two recommendations:

1) You should use an int[] instead of double[] for the array.  Any number that isn't an integer won't cleanly divide by 3.  When you are reading the file and adding to the array of numbers, use `n%1==0` in an if statement to check if the number read is in fact an integer and should be added to your array.  This will reduce the amount of recursive calls as the array will be potentially shorter assuming that you were able to dispose of some non integer values.

2) You can make a recursive method with just two parameters, the array of ints and one index.  Probably not necessary, but saves you the headache of worrying about passing indices.  HINT: startIndex never gets changed, your base case can be improved by knowing the length of the array.

Please feel free to ask me more questions in the comments if you want clarification/more hints.

Comment: Thank for the help! 

I made some of the changes that you told me about. It sort of works. Let say I enter 3 3 3 3.  It outputs 9 instead 12 same if I enter 9 9 9 3. It outputs 27 . It looks like its not reading the las number in the array Any suggestions?

Comment: @DiegoRodriguez Can you add the code you are using now as an edit to the original question?  It will be much easier to tell.

Answer (score 0):

... 
       String line = buffRead.readLine();

```
    try {
        while (line.equals("0") == false  && i < 100) {  
            nums[i] = Double.parseDouble(line);         
            i++;

            line = buffRead.readLine();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Array index out of bound");
    }

    int sum = computeSumDivisibleBy3(nums);

    System.out.print("The sum of the numbers divisible by 3 is " + sum + ('\n'));
```

.....

```
public static int computeSumDivisibleBy3(double[] numbers) {
    return _computeSumDivisibleBy3(numbers, 0);
}

    private static int _computeSumDivisibleBy3(double[] numbers, int currentIndex ) {

    int sum = 0;
    if (currentIndex != numbers.length) {
        int currentNumber = (int)numbers[currentIndex];
        sum =  (currentNumber % 3) == 0 ? currentNumber : 0;
        sum += _computeSumDivisibleBy3(numbers, ++currentIndex );
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: you should just overload the method rather than adding the `_` and the code is not very easy to read

Comment: The underscore is a personal preference, and I suppose I could have used less contractions but it seemed simple enough to me.